# Neo4j indexing and unique constraint

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j doesn't allow Index and Unique constraint on same property against a label. Does it mean ?

a) Unique Constraint is already indexed

b) Indexed property can have duplicate value across different node.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, (a) is true because creating a unique constraint adds an index on the property used in the constraint.

(b) is also true if there is no unique constraint defined on the property.

Answer (score 4):

**a) Unique Constraint is already indexed**
Yes.

**b) Indexed property can have duplicate value across different nodes.**
Yes, if only [index](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html) (without constraint) is added to that property.

You can find more info [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html).

**Important note:**

> Note that adding a uniqueness constraint on a property will also add
>   an index on that property, so you cannot add such an index separately.
>   Cypher will use that index for lookups just like other indexes. If you
>   drop a constraint and still want an index on the property, you will
>   have to create the index.